# Property binding for `value1` in Filter

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to bind a value from the model to a filter in SAPUI5?

My model:

```json
{
  "MasterItems": [
    {
      "ID" : "1.1",
      "ParentID" :  "1",
      "Text" : "a"
    },
    {
      "ID" : "2.1",
      "ParentID" :  "2",
      "Text" : "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Control:

```xml
<List items="{
  path: 'MasterItems>/MasterItems',
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'ParentID',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: '1'
    }
  ]
}">
```

As expected, the list shows only the first Item with the text `"1"`. 
But the `value1` is static. I want to know if I can do a property binding for `value1`?

Something like this:

```xml
value1: 'MasterItems>ParentID'
```

Now the filter SHOULD be dependent to the Model.

I already implemented the functionality within the controller but I think using aggregation binding would be better.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible. See https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

As Boghyon mentioned this is not possible. There is no way to bind filters directly to the model.

The only workaround for this is getting the binding of the aggregation you want to filter and set the filter in the controller:

Example snippet:

```
var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("SomeModelProperty", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "SomeValue");

var oControlBinding = this.getView().byId("idOfYourControl").getBinding("items");
oControlBinding.filter(oFilter);
```

You can also combine multiple filters by pushing them to an array an assign it then to the binding. See documentation https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter